# substring to return all values after delimiter

Tags: mysql

How do I get all the values after the first delimiter? In the following example I am expecting 'xyz@yahoo.com,pqr@company.com'

```
(02:40) mysql>select substring_index('abc@hotmail.com,xyz@yahoo.com,pqr@company.com', ',',  1) as first;
+-----------------+
| first           |
+-----------------+
| abc@hotmail.com |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

(02:41) mysql>select substring_index('abc@hotmail.com,xyz@yahoo.com,pqr@company.com', ',',  -1) as last;
+-----------------+
| last            |
+-----------------+
| pqr@company.com |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   select substring('abc@hotmail.com,xyz@yahoo.com,pqr@company.com',
   instr('abc@hotmail.com,xyz@yahoo.com,pqr@company.com', ',') + 1) as first;
```